# Callback onReadRemoteRssi() never gets called

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am facing some problem on android by reading RSSI from BLE device.
My code was always working and now i had to modify Gatt connection function to fix some issues and now i cant read RSSI anymore.

First of all i changed gatt function from

```
mGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);
```

to

```
mGatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, gattCallback,BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE);
```

So everytime i call this function

```
gatt.readRemoteRssi();
```

It never gets to its callback as before

```
public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status)
```

Reading RSSI was always working until i added the new argument value to connecGatt function.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I think that there can be something wrong with Android API. First of all with this code it was working 10% of time:

```
bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(this, true, new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "read rssi: " + gatt.readRemoteRssi());
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
        Log.d(TAG, "rssi: " + rssi);
    }
});
```

but I was able to improve it to work 70% of time by adding delay here:

```
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
        () -> Log.d(TAG, "read rssi: " + gatt.readRemoteRssi()), 3000);
    super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
}
```

However I've noticed that it stops working if signal strength is not changed. I mean that e.g. if device is near and rssi is -37 and I call this multiple times I get result only once. However if I move device back and call it I get result (e.g.  rssi -61) immediately and then when I move it closer again I also get result immediately. In such case my strategy is to read it from time to time and change value only when I really get result.